# Sort files according to the name containing numeric values

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing

I have files in my system like this -

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc     abcadm  14852497 Jul 23 01:11 ABCD_72_3_20210722_163502.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc     abcadm  14853145 Jul 23 01:11 ABCD_72_1_20210722_163502.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc     abcadm  14839699 Jul 23 01:11 ABCD_72_2_20210722_163502.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc     abcadm  14842673 Jul 23 01:11 ABCD_72_5_20210722_163502.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc     abcadm  14843811 Jul 23 01:11 ABCD_72_4_20210722_163502.csv
```

I want to sort those files to print only file name and with sorted manner like below:

```
ABCD_72_1_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_2_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_3_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_4_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_5_20210722_163502.csv
```

I am using the below to command to sort it in ascending order and to print just name but the list is not getting sorted.

```
ls -l | ABCD_72_[0-9]*_20210722_163502* | awk '{print $9}' | sort
```

Please suggest me where I am wrong or any alternative of this?

Answer (score 2):

First, don't parse the output of `ls`. We can modify the answer [to a different question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70614/how-to-output-only-file-names-with-spaces-in-ls-al) a bit to make it non-recursive, and then `find ./  -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\n"`, and you want it sorted, so pipe it into `sort`. The final command is

```sh
$ find ./  -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\n" | sort
```

As pointed out by @Rinzwind, if you want to numerically sort (so `2` could come before `12`), add `--numeric-sort` to the end of the command making it.

```sh
find ./  -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\n" | sort --numeric-sort
```

Comment: This breaks on *newline*, could do `-printf %f\\0 | sort -zn | xargs -0 -n 1`

Comment: @bac0n Then either edit my answer, or post your own. I didn’t consider newlines, because why would someone have a beeline in a file name?!?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply

```
ls -v -1
```

This can also be employed naturally with a file specification such as:

```
ls -v -1 ABCD*
```

or

```
ls -v -1 A*.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

If you switch to `zsh`, you can use its numeric glob qualifier:

```
   n      sets the NUMERIC_GLOB_SORT option for the current pattern
```

(see `Glob Qualifiers` under the `FILENAME GENERATION` section of `man zshexpn`).

Ex.

```
 % print -rC1 ABCD_*.csv(n)
ABCD_72_1_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_2_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_3_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_4_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_5_20210722_163502.csv
```

or (in reverse numeric order)

```
 % print -rC1 ABCD_*.csv(nOn)
ABCD_72_5_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_4_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_3_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_2_20210722_163502.csv
ABCD_72_1_20210722_163502.csv
```

Comment: Actually really fast.